# How do you get a Process' main window handle in C#?

Tags: c#, process, window, handle

The objective is to programmatically start a Windows Form, get its handle, and send info to its wndProc() function using Win Api's SendMessage() function.

I got the SendMessage() part taken care of but the problem now is getting the form's handle after the process has been started.

My first guess was that Process' MainWindowHandle property would get me the handle I am looking for, but after I start the process MainWindowHandle remains equal to 0 and the following code doesn't show the handle of the process I just started:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this and whether it can actually be done?

Comment: Try doing `Thread.Sleep(3000);` after starting the process, see if the result is any different. Also, what process are you starting? Does it even have a window?

Comment: it seems like putting the thread to sleep did the trick. thanks

Comment: @YoryeNathan can you put your comment as the answer?

Comment: @JeremyThompson Done. Also found some more stuff to add in there, to actually make it answer-worthy.

Comment: @JeremyThompson What was the point of it, anyways? It doesn't look like he is aware of the Acceptance feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes the Process takes a second the set up everything, but the object is returned immediately.

For that reason, you should wait a little bit, in order to let the Process really get it started, and then it's MainWindowHandle will be set appropriately, ready to be consumed.

```
var proc = Process.Start("notepad");

Thread.Sleep(1000); // This will wait 1 second

var handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
```

Another way to do it in a more smart fashion would be:

```
var proc = Process.Start("notepad");

try
{
    while (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Discard cached information about the process
        // because MainWindowHandle might be cached.
        proc.Refresh();

        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    var handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
}
catch
{
    // The process has probably exited,
    // so accessing MainWindowHandle threw an exception
}
```

That will cause the process to start, and wait until the MainWindowHandle isn't empty.

Comment: actually Yorye, I think I would be remiss if I don't mention that based on my observations, your second approach is not going to work, because, for some reason, if you access MainWindowHandle before it's been initialized, it doesn't get initialized at all, meaning that your while loop will run forever. Why is it this way? I don't know, but try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @JohnSmith You're right, the information is being cached in the object. Calling the `Refresh` method discards that cached information, so the next time you access the `MainWindowHandle` property, it will retrieve it from the actual window, as needed. See update of my post.

Comment: Sometimes I'm learning new things from my own answers 3 years ago.

Comment: The loop with proc.Refresh() solved my problem.